# asp.net FileUpload.FileName returns full path in ie when not needed

Tags: asp.net

From what i understand for asp.net FileUpload.FileName ruturns the full path while in firefox it returns just the filename. How would i remove the path from the returned string as i just need the html encoded filename.

Comment: `FileName` ist just the filename even in IE beginning with IE8. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/07/27/uploading-a-file-using-fileupload-control-fails-in-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) static class to get the filename.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(somePath);
```

And the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) static class to encode it.

```
var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(fileName);
```

Comment: Even with
`fileName = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Path.GetFileName(fileBrowser.PostedFile.FileName))` it still returns the full path

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by full path. Because if you call `Path.GetFileName("C:\mypath\myfile.txt");` then you will get back `"myfile.txt"`

Comment: @Reahreic - I'm not sure what to tell you. I can guarantee that `Path.GetFileName` works as expected. You can test this easily by writing a unit test and passing in your full path. It will return `"xxyyzz.png"`

Comment: It Worked, Apparently i couldn't see the damn function farther down the line that was overriding the stripped path with the full path... Im #$^!!@$*-off now... Thank you for helping

Answer (score 5):

So there is an IE setting (not just in IE8 but newer versions as well) under Tools -> Internet Options -> Security that allows you to include or exclude the local path on file uploads.

[image: IE8 Local Directory Path Setting]

For that reason, if you are not wanting to keep full path info, it is safest to explicitly strip the path if you are wanting to support IE (not sure if any other browsers have such a setting).

As mentioned by Josh, Path.GetFileName(...) is a good option. You can also use string.Split combined with Linq.

```
string fileNameOnly = somePath.Split('\\').Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Path.GetFileName(Request.Files["file"].FileName)
```